# kafka-based OSN in local single-host Fabric network, But NO logs in the kafka containers when I perform transactions

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I have set up a fabric netowork consisting of 1org: 1CA, 1peer, 1orderer, couchdb.

Now, my approach for setting up kafka-based ordering service was:
In the configtx file 
  1. I made orderer type to kafka.
  2. Added a single orderer address (orderer.example.com)
  3. Added 4 kafka brokers(kafka0.example.com:9092...)

Then I generated the genesis and channel config files using the above set up in the configtx.

Then I Updated my docker-compose.yaml file to include the kafka and zookeeper containers.

Finally brought up the entire network using `docker-compose -f ... up -d`

The problem is when I submit transactions, I see the orderer logs updating, but no change or update in the kafka logs. Although the orderer shows some kafka related logs like [kafka/consensus]....

```
2019-07-27 17:29:32.646 UTC [orderer/common/blockcutter] Ordered -> DEBU 3c1 Enqueuing message into batch
2019-07-27 17:29:32.646 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] func1 -> DEBU 3c2 [channel: mychannel] Ordering results: items in batch = 0, pending = true
2019-07-27 17:29:32.646 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] func1 -> DEBU 3c3 [channel: mychannel] Just began 2s batch timer
2019-07-27 17:29:32.647 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] enqueue -> DEBU 3c4 [channel: mychannel] Envelope enqueued successfully
2019-07-27 17:29:32.647 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 3c5 [channel: mychannel] Broadcast has successfully enqueued message of type ENDORSER_TRANSACTION from 172.22.0.14:36112
2019-07-27 17:29:32.651 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 3c7 Error reading from 172.22.0.14:36112: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-07-27 17:29:32.651 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 3c8 Closing Broadcast stream
2019-07-27 17:29:34.647 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] sendTimeToCut -> DEBU 3c9 [channel: mychannel] Time-to-cut block 2 timer expired
2019-07-27 17:29:34.707 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] processMessagesToBlocks -> DEBU 3ca [channel: mychannel] Successfully unmarshalled consumed message, offset is 6. Inspecting type...
2019-07-27 17:29:34.707 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] processTimeToCut -> DEBU 3cb [channel: mychannel] It's a time-to-cut message for block 2
2019-07-27 17:29:34.707 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] processTimeToCut -> DEBU 3cc [channel: mychannel] Nil'd the timer
2019-07-27 17:29:34.707 UTC [orderer/consensus/kafka] processTimeToCut -> DEBU 3cd [channel: mychannel] Proper time-to-cut received, just cut block 2
```

The kafka logs only update when the kafka broker starts and channel is created etc. I am confused whether my kafka based ordering is working or is it just working like a solo orderer.

[image: image desc]
I have also observed the orderer communication with the brockers perriodically